# How can one override bash Ctrl+C to be more fish-like

Tags: bash, configuration, tty, fish, stty

I find myself using bash more often than not on remote machines even though `fish` is my preferred shell. Fish has small, but nice feature that when you hit Ctrl+C something like this happens:

```
if command running
   send SIGINT
else
   clear line (don't start a new one)
```

It would be nice to be able to do this in bash too.

I imagine it would involve trapping SIGINT, which comes from `stty` being configured to send it once Ctrl+C is hit, but I haven't found out how to execute the pseudo-code above.

**What I've tried**

`trap 'tput dl1' SIGINT`

which clears the line, but still continues to start a new line/prompt (it's like hitting enter on an empty prompt) and does so **only** if I've not navigated in history :\

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a bit of fiddling with [`trap`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html), [`tput`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) and [`terminfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo), I think I figured it out ([thanks to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319932/clear-all-text-on-current-line-from-a-bash-script)).

For a standard commandline with only 1 line e.g `bash-4.3$ echo something here`

`trap 'tput dl1; tput cuu1' SIGINT` is what I needed.

bash will:

- delete the line
- move the cursor up

and finally start a new line (hence the *move the cursor up*).

If your commandline has 2 or more lines e.g

```
name@host /path/to/some/dir
$ echo something here
```

Then another `tput dl1; tput cuu1` will have to be added, to delete the extra line --> `trap 'tput dl1; tput cuu1; tput dl1; tput cuu1' SIGINT`

I guess I'll see if this has any adverse effects.